# Hive is automatically rounding of the precision

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am doing a division operation in hive and it seems like automatically rounding of the values. Is there a way i can avoid this.

**Example**

```
 select cast(600/27701.47 as decimal(31,20));
+-------------------------+
|           _c0           |
+-------------------------+
| 0.02165950000000000000  |
+-------------------------+
```

**Expected value:**

```
0.0216595003803047
```

I am using hive on EMR - Hive 2.3.6-amzn-1

Answer (score 0):

What version do you use?

In Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.14.2 it's working well.

[image]

Comment: Cloudera has lots of patches to solve this kind of issues. We also faced similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit late in responding, but I have a tricky answer for others.

`select cast(600 as varchar(10))/cast(27701.47 as varchar(10));`

It worked for me.